# Нужно написать запрос postgresql ( aginity workbench)

Tags: postgresql, max, min

Вывести всех женщин (customer_pk) и их макс доход. Вывести нужно тех, у которых максимальный доход за все время как минимум в три раза больше, чем минимальный за все время. Таблица table1 выглядит так (customer_pk,firstnm,middlenm,lastnm,income)
Правильно ли написан запрос?

```
SELECT customer_pk,maximum
  FROM (
   select customer_pk,
          min(income) as minimum, 
          max(income) as maximum
     from table1
    where middlenm like '%НА'
    group by customer_pk
  )as t
 WHERE t.maximum >= 3*t. minimum
```

Comment: выглядит нормально. а вообще, запускайте на тестовых данных и смотрите верен ли результат. спрашивать у сторонних людей, которые не знают, что лежит у вас в БД и какие могут быть в связи с этим нюансы, бесполезно (если при этом не приводите конечно структуру БД с описанием что где и примером данных)

Comment: Данных слишком много и я не могу проверит правильность выполнения запроса

Comment: А мы тем более не эксрасенсы и не можем сказать верно ли он будет работать. Я например не нахожу очевидным, что условие `middlenm like '%НА'` выведет именно женщин